# Animated series about an inventor, a soldier, a monster and a girl

Tags: story-identification, animation, animated-series

I was remembering some animated series I have seen when I was a kid (late 1980s - beginning 1990s) about an inventor (he was an old man), a soldier (I think it could be an animated tin soldier?), a friendly monster (maybe a bigfoot or something similar) and a girl (I think she was related to the inventor).

As you can see I have a very vague memory about this series but I think it was **not** an anime.

I remember some episode where the soldier got possessed and was confronted by the monster and he (the soldier) matches his strength when usually the monster was stronger.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Force Check this. Looks familiar to me, but I didn't watch that cartoon. If that is it, I will make full answer. It ran around 1994.  Episode here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kn1J_eZ1o0

Comment: Hi, @jo1storm. Thanks, but this isn't the cartoon I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have found it after reading a long article about cartoons of the 80s! The serie was [The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Teddy_Ruxpin). It features a inventor (Newton Gimmick), a yeti-like monster (The Wooly Whatsit), a soldier (prince Arin) and a girl (princess Aruzia). I completely forgot about the eponymous Teddy Ruxpin or Grubby.

The chapter where the soldier where possessed seems to be S01E03 as for Wikipedia summary:

> Teddy, Grubby, Gimmick, Prince Arin was at the jungle until they met
>   the Grunges just then, Prince Arin fell into the soup and he is too
>   strong, and was returned to himself.

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to self accept.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities for inventor cartoons, but I can't seem to find anything to fit your other points.

Mad Scientist (an aborted Mattel toy tie-in) from 1988:

[Dr Snuggles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Snuggles) - a short-lived show from 1979 which was shown as repeats into the 90s:

Comment: Thanks! I am afraid that these series are not the one I am looking for. This serie has proben very difficult to find. I have googled all terms I remember and I cannot find it.